# How to create a placeholder for a specific plugin in django-cms 3.0.0

Tags: django-cms

How do i create a placeholder that can only be filled with a specific plugin?
I'd like to create a template in **django-cms 3.0.0.beta2**, with a placeholder only for the pictures plugin. I couldn't find any option in the docs.

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/develop/advanced/templatetags.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the placeholder "slot name" (first argument to `{% placeholder %}` or first argument to `PlaceholderField`, depending on which you use) and [`CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf) you can limit a placeholder to only allow a single type of plugin.

For example: if you have a placeholder in your template which looks like `{% placeholder 'main_image' %}`, the corresponding `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` value in `settings.py` would be:

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'main_image': {
        'plugins': ['PicturePlugin']
    }
}
```

Comment: The structure of the documentation seems to have changed a bit, so for the current stable (v3.1), it's here: http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/3.1/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf.